# camera plugin not working with cordova 6.5.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am getting a problem with camera plugin as it is not working and crashing. It was working before but when i update codova 6.5.0 it stop opening camera activity and crashing now. Here is what i am getting on console:

```
E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method    'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser  android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageM anager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Can someone have idea why it is given this error.

Comment: did you try by reinstalling the plugin ??

Comment: can you tell me how i can do this ?

Comment: remove plugin by using cordova plugin rm <PLUGIN_NAME> and add it by using cordova plugin add <PLUGIN_NAME>

Answer (score 1):

I did the following changes to make it work again.
add this entry into your Manifest.xml:

```
 <provider android:authorities="com.yourApp.provider" android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

create a xml file(provider_paths.xml) in res/xml/ with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```